# Как создать градиентный фон на всю web страницу?

Tags: css, css3, изображения, оптимизация, background

Подскажите, пожалуйста, реально ли градиентами (или какой другой технологией) сделать фоновое изображение - подложку для всей страницы.
 Я пробовал через `radial gradient`, но  пока нужного результата не вышло (просто фото идет как `background-image` на всё `body` и не хочется 3мБ вбрасывать, а при сжатии данного фото теряю в качестве) самая большая проблема с облачками.

[image: Фон]

Comment: Обратитесь к Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator, на этом ресурсе можно создать подобный беграунд и получите полный CSS-cod.

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант решения

```css
html,body{
  background:#222;
  height:100%;
}
.body_elem{
  height:100%;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to left,#111,#221c44);
  filter:blur(10px);
}
.elem1{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  border-radius:30em/19em;
    background:linear-gradient(to left,#111,#221c44);
  transform:rotate(30deg)translateY(90px);
  filter:blur(40px);
}
.elem1-1{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background:#fff;
  transform:translate(205px,105px);
  filter:blur(50px);
}
.elem2{
  width:50%;
  height:50%;
  border-radius:30em/19em;
    background:linear-gradient(to left,#111,#221c44);
  transform:rotate(-20deg)translateY(-80px);
  filter:blur(10px);
  float:right;
}
.elem2-1{
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  background:#222;
  transform:rotate(80deg);
  border-radius:80em/30em;
  filter:blur(100px
  );
}

.body-elem-2{
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0; right:0;
  width:80%;
  margin:auto;
}
h2{
  color:#fff;
  font-family:Verdana, serif;
  font-size:2em;
}
.body-elem-2 p{
  color:#fbfbfb;
  font-size:1.4em;
  font-family:"Times New Roman", sans-serif;
}
img{
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="body_elem">
<div class="elem1">
  <div class="elem1-1"></div>
</div>
<div class="elem2">
  <div class="elem2-1"></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="body-elem-2">
  <h2>New post</h2>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quis hic nostrum totam, eius illo magnam alias eveniet, qui laborum dolores fuga pariatur sapiente aperiam quae, blanditiis atque. Minima, quasi veniam?</p>
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/550x250" alt="">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae, esse eveniet nam autem recusandae quas voluptates totam eligendi dolorum. Cum, dolorem rerum ullam, cumque ad fuga quas incidunt eum laboriosam blanditiis, nesciunt fugit pariatur perferendis nemo distinctio aspernatur animi ratione!</p>
</div>
```

Comment: смотреть на весь экран

Comment: Хех, прикольно. Но поддерживают ли это дело IE10-12?

Comment: не знаю...но есть браузер под ms-dos который даже css не знает ... ещё о нём думать ?

Comment: зачем, когда статистика на Google Analytics показывает мне примерно по 20% на сайт людей с IE10-12 и еще 10% на Edge. О них тоже стоит думать(хотя ой как лень).

Comment: я сам на edge , на нём работает ... а на всё остальное мне до лампочки ... если будет реальная задача я её сделаю на svg

Comment: @МаксимЛенский а это виртуальная задача?))

Comment: @Избытоксусликов   я не понял Вас