# Как сделать сложный градиент?

Tags: css, css3, градиент

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно сделать что-то подобное, как на картинке, фоном. Как лучше поступить и что использовать: комбинацию линейных и радиальных градиентов, box-shadow или что-то ещё?

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно переоткрыть вопрос

Comment: не надо переоткрывать. просто внесите дополнение (нажав [edit])

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/797957/33274

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!